# Can't SELECT DISTINCT in GROUP_CONCAT DERIVED Query

Tags: mysql, sql

In this [Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d9b39/1/0):

```
SELECT u.`id`, nc.`con` FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT n.`uid`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.`content`) AS `con` 
  FROM `names` n
  INNER JOIN `contents` c ON n.`uid` = c.`aid`
  GROUP BY n.`uid`
) nc ON nc.`uid` = u.`id`
WHERE u.`age` = 15
```

I want to `SELECT DISTINCT c.content` values **efficiently**,

I don't want to use `DISTINCT` at all, And if possible want to use `GROUP BY`, Since using `DISTINCT` is like hidding the problem,

Right now I've made this Query, But it doesn't even `SELECT DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT` with many `ROW`s.

What I want is to get without using `DISTINCT` if possible the result:

```
con: A, B
```

What I get is the result:

```
con: A,B,B,A,A,B
```

If there is a better way to do this I'm open for it.

Comment: Do the distinct concat before joining

Comment: @Used_By_Already I get the values depending on a selected column `u.id` that is selected before join in the query itself.

Comment: What does your data in `c.content` look like before hitting it with `group_concat` is it already partially concatenated?

Comment: @JNevill without using `group_concat`?  I get `A` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might `GROUP BY`  on subquery then `group_concat` the field.

You can try it.

```
SELECT u.`id`, group_concat(nc.`con`)
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT n.`uid`, c.`content` AS `con` 
  FROM `names` n
  INNER JOIN `contents` c ON n.`uid` = c.`aid`
  GROUP BY n.`uid`,c.`content`
) nc ON nc.`uid` = u.`id`
WHERE u.`age` = 15
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d9b39/17)

Comment: Wouldn't `GROUP BY c.'content'` be enought? Also I would like to ask, Is it always better to handle it like this? `GROUP BY` in the `JOIN` and `group_concat` out of the `JOIN`? Or there is no performance effect?

Comment: In this case `GROUP BY c.'content'` will be enought.
I don't have more detailed info from tables.
I couldn't tell you is always better to handle it like this.
Because different scenarios will have different solutions

Comment: I only have two scenarios in this case, One has `duplicates` which you've solved, And another has no `duplicates`, Which I use the same Query I used in the Question, Do you recommend using yours instead of mine in this scenario too?

Comment: Which solutions was your desire?If you want to have no duplicates you can use mine solution.
I think the DB optimiser should be smart enough.It will fine the best solution.